# Trying to add 2 (JLabel, JSlider) TO A Panel with BorderLayout, only JSlider gets drawn

Tags: java, swing

I have copy my code to display a text feild and a JSlider) from a project that usses a JFrame

My new project usses a  JInternalFrame, and only the slider is drawn.  If I comment out the code it will draw the text field, seems like it only wonts to draw 1 control.

**code**

```
    JPanel containerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout() );
    cDrawComponent mDrawComponent = new cDrawComponent();  
    containerPanel.add(mDrawComponent,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JLabel mJLabel=new JLabel("000");
    mJSlider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 1000,500);
    JPanel sliderPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout() );
```

// TRYING TO ADD 2 CONPOMENTS ONLY SLIDER IS SHOWN
        sliderPanel.add(mJLabel);
        sliderPanel.add(mJSlider);
        containerPanel.add(sliderPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

```
    class SliderListener implements ChangeListener {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            JSlider source = (JSlider) e.getSource();
            ted++;
            if (!source.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                {
                    sliderPes = (int) source.getValue();
                    int max=source.getMaximum();                
                    scrollPes=max-sliderPes;
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    mJSlider.addChangeListener(new SliderListener());
    add(containerPanel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
sliderPanel.add(mJLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

The BorderLayout can show only one component at the center (Default, if ommited). That's usually the last one, that got added.